# Is there iostat-similar tool that tracks swap area activity and page cache miss?

Tags: swap, iostat

The iostat tool is able to tell us cpu usage, disk r/w throughput second-by-second.

Is there a similar tool to track swap area activity and page cache miss?

For example, the tool should tell us the magnitude of swap area activity and number of page cache miss second-by-second.

Answer (score 0):

`sar -B` provides a lot of paging stats, including page faults per second.

The `-S` option gives you swap space utilization, `-W` swapin/swapout stats.

`vmstat` also provides the equivalent of `sar -W`.

All? or most? of the metrics are also available in `/proc/meminfo`. The `proc` manual page tells you what the various lines mean.

Comment: Thanks. It's working for me. The finest granularity seems to be 1 minute. But it's should be good enough for me. I can change the default 10min to 1min and get a more accurate picture.

Comment: This is strange. On the Linux server that I am currently working on (Ubuntu 22), *sar -B 1* prints paging statistics ever second.

Comment: By the way, if you use a 600 second interval, the data is not less accurate at all, it's just less fine-grained. All that sar does is reporting data that the kernel generates (see /proc/meminfo). Besides, in production, a one-minute (let alone one-second) interval risks stressing the system and generating too much data for your filesystem, and too much data for effective analysis. Therefore, 10 minutes is not only the default for sar, but a reasonable interval for any solution that logs such metrics.